# How do I remap Vim's ctrl+o?

Tags: vim

I'd like to use <kbd>Control+O</kbd> (normal mode) for something else in Vim, and <kbd>Alt+left</kbd> for jump back (what <kbd>Control+O</kbd> usually does). Usually I'd simply map <kbd>Alt+left</kbd> to whatever command used to be bound to <kbd>Control+O</kbd>, but I can't seem to find any (for example, there's no :back or :jumpback).

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just map the new key to the old key, but use noremap (no re-map), so that the mapping uses the original meaning of any key on the right side of the mapping and not any new mapping that you might have given to that key.

As an example, if you

```
:map a b
:map b c
```

and you type `a`, you will execute the function originally bound to `c`. However, if you

```
:noremap a b
:noremap b c
```

and you type `a`, you will execute the function originally bound to `b`.

So in your case, your mapping would be

```
:nnoremap <Alt-Left> <C-O>
```

or

```
:nnoremap <A-Left> <C-O>
```

That will let you map `<C-O>` to something else.

Note: Neither of those mappings work for me on the system I'm currently using, even though the Vim documentation suggests that they should, butt this does:

```
:nnoremap <M-Left> <C-O>
```

Comment: its not working.